# Replacing a column in a dataframe raises ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Tags: pandas, dataframe

There is a description of using the replace method:

```
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-values-of-a-dataframe-with-the-value-of-another-dataframe-in-pandas/][1]
```

Unfortunately, I have an error during replacing columns of dataframe with a column from another dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

# initialise data of lists.
colors = {
    "first_set": ["99", "88", "77", "66", "55", "44", "33", "22"],
    "second_set": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
}

color = {
    "first_set": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
    "second_set": ["VI", "IN", "BL", "GR", "YE", "OR", "RE", "WI"],
}
# Calling DataFrame constructor on list
df = pd.DataFrame(colors, columns=["first_set", "second_set"])
df1 = pd.DataFrame(color, columns=["first_set", "second_set"])

# Display the Output
display(df)
display(df1)
```

Here is a code with an error:

```py
# replace column of one DataFrame with
# the column of another DataFrame
ser1 = df1["first_set"]
ser2 = df["second_set"]
print(ser1)
print(ser2)
df["second_set"] = df1.replace(to_replace=ser1, value=ser2)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28648/2104797653.py in 
> 5 print(ser1)
> 6 print(ser2)
> ----> 7 df['second_set'] = df1.replace(to_replace=ser1,value=ser2)
>
> ~.virtualenvs\01_python_packages-rD-UbwAe\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> in **setitem**(self, key, value)    3600
> self._setitem_array(key, value)    3601         elif isinstance(value,
> DataFrame):
> -> 3602             self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)    3603         elif (    3604             is_list_like(value)
>
> ~.virtualenvs\01_python_packages-rD-UbwAe\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> in _set_item_frame_value(self, key, value)    3727
> len_cols = 1 if is_scalar(cols) else len(cols)    3728             if
> len_cols != len(value.columns):
> -> 3729                 raise ValueError("Columns must be same length as key")    3730     3731             # align right-hand-side columns
> if self.columns
>
> ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: Your sample code does not produce this error.

Comment: Maybe I have some problem with a package?

Comment: The problem wasn't in replace method. There was a problem in the assignment operation.